# DataGridView Footer

Tags: datagridview, footer

I'm working in Windows Application. I have a form which is having a DataGridView control.

I'm binding DataGridView using DataGridView.DataSource property.

Can anyone please tell me how to show footer to the DataGridView so that I can show the SUM of related columns.

Thanks in advance !

D Shahu

Comment: Try out this link:[Add a footer to a datagridview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056678/datagridview-column-footer-c-net-winforms

Comment: Try out this link:[Add a footer to a datagridview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056678/datagridview-column-footer-c-net-winforms